# Windows Server Redirect Issue

Tags: windows-services, robots.txt

I am dealing with some client's that use Windows servers and as such do not support .htaccess files.  This is not a huge deal but, my concern is this:

I have a rule set up in my .htaccess file to redirect the non-www version of the site to the www version. This makes the URL's look nicer and prevents duplicate content being indexed.

However, there does not seem to be a simple way to do this on a Windows server.  I have read through tutorials on setting up a web.config file but, my Windows server experience is very limited and many times I only have FTP access to the site (no server access).

Any ideas on a quick and fairly simple solution, that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create web.config (in the root directory) file with the next content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) (at least version 2.0) has to be installed.

Comment: That works great for one of the sites!  However, it did not work for another one.  What if they do not have the URL Rewrite Module installed?

Comment: Try to coordinate installation of the Rewrite module - it's generaly accepted extension.
On the other hand you can write your own module - it's pretty simple (if you need support I can write it for you tomorrow).

Comment: That's very kind of you but, I'm not even familiar with how you add a module/extension.

Comment: Using this config file, how could I also strip off the filename of the index page, so it 301 redirects to the root.  For example: http://www.domain.com/index.html redirects to http://www.domain.com/

Answer (score 1):

To use custom module create file `CanonicalRedirectModule.cs` in folder `App_Code` it the root folder of the Web Site Application with next content:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class CanonicalRedirectModule : IHttpModule
{
    public const string configKeyCanonicalHostName = "CanonicalHostName";

    private string configCanonicalHostName;

    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        this.configCanonicalHostName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKeyCanonicalHostName];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.configCanonicalHostName))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("Can't find application setting {0} in configuration file (/configuration/appSettings/add/...).", configKeyCanonicalHostName);
//#if !DEBUG
//            return;
//#endif
        }

        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    #endregion

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (app.Request.Url.Host != this.configCanonicalHostName) //&& !app.Request.IsLocal
        {
            UriBuilder newUrl = new UriBuilder(app.Request.Url);
            newUrl.Host = this.configCanonicalHostName;

            app.Response.Redirect(newUrl.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

Then configure module in `web.config`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<system.web>
  <!-- Configuration for classic pipeline mode -->
  <httpModules>
    <add name="CanonicalRedirectModule" type="CanonicalRedirectModule"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <!-- Configuration for integrated pipeline mode -->
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
    <add name="CanonicalRedirectModule" type="CanonicalRedirectModule"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working.  I copied out the module gave it the correct name and put it in a folder (in the root) called App_Code.  Then I put the web.config above in the root.  Am I missing something?  Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information about server environment (IIS version, ASP.NET version)

Comment: Thats the thing, I have no way of finding that out.  I am only able to get FTP access.

Comment: The best way is to contact your hosting provider support and ask them for IIS server version, ASP.NET version and enabled modules.
Very basic information is in server variable named SERVER_SOFTWARE.

In aspx file you can check it by putting next line into a blank file (test.aspx):
    <%= Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_SOFTWARE")%>

In php file you can check it by putting next line into a blank file (test.php):
    <?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]; ?>